# flash menu link

Tags: flash

i am working on flash menu. in this menu i make a 4 tabs.. in each tabs i have 2 text.. in this text i have to give a link on google.com. and i also have to add a underline when my mouse over the text.

then how to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Text Tool object on the stage, right?
1) Click on it
2) Properties Inspector
3) Maximize "options" panel
4) Put url in the URL textbox... Make sure you put the http:// if you're linking to another website.
    -so that mean you would put `http://www.google.com` as your url

Instructions are for Flash CS4

Comment: thanks for your reply.

i done this. i give a link on it and its working. but when i give a up and over on the text then underline is showing..

how to do this. if u have any idea then please give me...

Comment: I only know how to do that with actionscript.